# @Retention(RetentionPolicty.Source) and @Inherited

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to have both `@Retention(Source)` and `@Inherited` functioning on an annotation definition or does RetentionPolicy.Source cancels Inherited annotation?

In my tests, latter seems to be the outcome however I couldn't find any reference for this, which is what I'm looking for.

I was hoping retention policy at source level and inherited would work with help from processing environment.

Comment: I don't understand your doubt. Why would it cancel the annotation? (What does it even mean to cancel an annotation?)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "RetentionPolicy.Source cancels Inherited annotation" = inherited doesn't function any more.

Answer (score 0):

`@Retention` and `@Inherited` serve different purposes.

The javadoc of `@Retention` states that it

> Indicates how long annotations with the annotated type are to be retained.

The javadoc of `@Inherited` states that it

> Indicates that an annotation type is automatically inherited.

An annotation type cannot be inherited if it doesn't exist.

- If the annotation exists at `SOURCE` level, then `@Inherited` will also work at `SOURCE` level.
- If the annotation exists at `CLASS` level, then `@Inherited` will also work at `CLASS` level.
- If the annotation exists at `RUNTIME` level, then `@Inherited` will also work at `RUNTIME` level.

Comment: So first conclusion is having SOURCE and Inherited is useless?

Comment: @auselen No, you could still use it in a compiler (or whatever source code parser).

Comment: What kind of outcome you would expect then?

Comment: @auselen If the annotated class type didn't have the `@Inherited` annotated annotation, its parent class types would be checked.

Comment: @auselen _I didn't get that._ as in you didn't understand what I wrote or that's not the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: I didn't understand :). To me having source and inherited at the same time seems like a no go. Since compiler would first compile superclass, discard annotation and then compile subclass and that won't have the annotation any more. That's logical to me, however I'm looking for some kind of reference to say if tools should have more extended behaviour.

Comment: @auselen `SOURCE` level is for a pre-compile operation, before a `.class` file is generated. It's useful for IDEs and compilers. Take `@SuppressWarnings` for example.

Comment: which makes "having SOURCE and Inherited is useless" ?

Comment: @auselen You seem to only be thinking of this at a RUNTIME analysis through `Class#getAnnotation(..)`. For `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`, the rules of `@Inherited` would still have to be satisfied in the byte code. Similarly, at `SOURCE, the rules would have to be satisfied when analyzing the source code.